# Spring Security: CookieTheftException is thrown when multiple webservice call at same time with same "rememberMeCookie"

Tags: angularjs, web-services, spring-security

In my application  we are using angularJS framework  and Spring rest webservices.

PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices is used for spring security.

After successful login there are 4 parallel webservice calls to get user details and for other activities. All the processes gives same "rememberMeCookie" in AbstractRememberMeServices(method - autoLogin, line no - 95).

In database token is created in table "PERSISTENT_LOGINS" after login and is modified after the second webservice call to get user details.

When third webservice call executes there is a mismatch between "rememberMeCookie" and token generated from tokenRepository (line no - 99) which throws CookieTheftException.

How can I resolve the problem?